# What is the best way to move out-of-order Access records into the proper order by using a locked ID field?

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

I have roughly 1500 records in an Access database. I have a field `ID` that acts as the primary key, and as such cannot be manually changed. After looking through the original Excel sheet these records were kept in, I noticed that a few records in Excel were missing from the Access database. After going through all of them, I added the three missing records into Access.

This database stores records in date order, grouped by a manufacturer. Ex. records from Manufacturer1 collected during week 1 of June '16 are all located together, and records from Manufacturer2 collected during week 2 of June '16 are stored directly afterwards. This is important for us because the data in this database often needs to be looked at visually, so keeping things in date order is essential. There is also a macro that export the data to an Excel sheet and formats it to be easier to read, which exports the records in the order in which they are stored (by the `ID` field). This is a problem because the three missing records are from years past - now they are in the middle of records from 2018. The `ID`s they were assigned upon entry keeps them in that location.

Is there a way to reliably insert these records into the database in the location at which they should be? Such as shifting the values of other records `ID` fields down by 3 to allow room for the missing records? I know I can probably manually have those three records move to the desired location in the macro that exports to Excel, but I'd rather have a less hacky solution that could work if a similar problem happens again.

Comment: Order in a database table is NEVER guaranteed.  This has to do with inserts/updates/deletes and how the records are tracked in the file system object.   Your safest bet would be to create a view/query which applies the desired order by; this way order can be guaranteed

Comment: As a general concept, tables in a database have no specific order. They are a sort of collection of records. What makes order is the way in which you retrieve them. For instance, you would issue a command `select .... from .... order by...`. So, the `order by` part is what determines the way the data is being passed back to you (or your end-user application).

Answer (score 1):

The order of data in a database is of no interest to the database - it's the relation between data that matters.

To always view your data in the order you want use the `ORDER BY` clause in an SQL statement.  Generally you can add data to the underlying table directly through the query - unless you've got many-to-one type queries where your update would need to affect more than one record.

```
SELECT FieldName1, FieldName2, . . . .
FROM   MyDataTable
ORDER BY Manufacturer, Date
```

Edit:  Even here you'll be adding new records to the bottom of the dataset, but refreshing the query will move the records to the correct order.